# Laravel unit test always expects route? can't we give a public file URL?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

Received status code 404 while I was trying to test a file "test/index.php" in public folder, as below:

```
$this->visit('http://localhost.com/test')
     ->see('Hello');
```

There is index.php file within the test folder. I am able to access test in my browser via `localhost.com/test/`.

Does unit testing in Laravel always expects only route? like `->visit(some route)`? Can we even test public folder files?

Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated

Comment: A couple things in your question don't make sense. Usually, the `public` folder doesn't show up in the URL, and you say the file is `test.php` but you're trying to access it as `test` without an extension.

Comment: There is a index.php file in test folder within public folder.
public/test/index.php

I can access it from browser with localhost/test

Comment: It would appear there's special handling for `localhost` in the `visit` function. `$this->visit('https://www.google.com/');` works fine.

Comment: Yeah, In case of google it is working, I pushed my code to server and tried with `$this->visit('https://www.mywebsite.com/test');` it is still not working but as i said `https://www.mywebsite.com/test` works fine in browser.

Comment: What you really mean is if you are serving a page on your local machine on xampp (`http://localhost/testsite/testpage.html`) and try to access that in phpunit in an instance of laravel running on the same machine, you are unable to reach that `testpage.html`?

Comment: Yes, but not only in local machine, i tried uploading this test folder in live server and tried to access it through (http://mywebsite/test/index.php) .

`$this->visit('http://mywebsite.com/test')
        ->see('Hello');`

This wasn't working either.

Comment: `$this->visit('https://www.google.com/');` I am sure this is not working. if you just used `->see('Google')`, nowdays every page has google in it somewhere or other.